# Items not being added to task list on todolist

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently building a to do list and having trouble adding to the list. I feel like everything should work but when write in the add task bar and then press add task nothing appears in the task list.

the current .js file

```
window.addEventListener ('load', () => { 
const form = document.querySelector( "#new-task-form"); 
const input = document.querySelector("#new-task-input"); 
const list_el = document.querySelector("#tasks");


form.addEventListener ('Submit',(e) => {
    e.preventdefault() ; //stops page refreshing when form submitted

    const task = input.value;
    
    if (!task) {
        alert("Please enter a task!") ;
        return
    } 
    
   const_task_el = document.createElement("div")
   task_el.classList.add("task");

   const task_content_el = document.createElement("div")
   task_content_el.classList.add("content");
   task_content_el.innerText =  task ;

   task_el.appendChild(task_content_el)
   list_el.appendChild(task_el)
})
```

ive checked for spelling mistakes in id names but cant help to find the issue. the html file is like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en"> 
<head> 
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<title>YETIS TO DO LIST</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href = "main.css" /> 
</head> 

<body> 
<header> 
<h1>TO DO LIST</h1> 
<form id = "new-task-form"> 
<input type ="text" 
 id ="new-task-input" 
 name ="new-task-input" placeholder ="What would you like to do today?"
/>
    <input 
         type ="submit" 
         id = "new-task-add"
         value ="Add task" /> 
      
    </form>

</header>
<main> 
<section class="taskslist"> 
<h2>Tasks</h2> 
<div id="tasks">

<!--<div class="task">
<div class="content">
 <input type ="text" 
   class ="text" 
    value = "My first task" 
   readonly

</div> 
 <div class="actions"> 
 <button class="edit">Edit</button>
 <button class="delete">Delete</button> --> 

</div> 
</section> 
</main>
 <script src="main.js"></script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `const_task_el` seems like it should be `const task_el` no?

Comment: ive changed this and it hasnt worked.  not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

1. fix spelling error to `preventdefault()` to `preventDefault()`
2. fix this line `const_task_el = document.createElement("div")` to `const task_el = document.createElement('div')` and check if it works or not

Comment: ive just tried this and it hasnt seem to worked.

Comment: preventDefault() fix this it should work

Comment: still not working how it should unfortunately

Comment: nothing i can do

Comment: because your code need refactor. there is only two error first is variable and second is spelling mistake in preventDefault() ( if refreshes every time you add something). I can google meet if you want to and fix there.

Comment: i will try to fix it, if not i will let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The name of the form event is 'submit', all lowercase, not 'Submit'. So you are never executing your DOM insertion code.

You are also missing  })  at the end of your Javascript file (i.e. to end your "load" event listener code)

These of course are in addition to the two things already mentioned:

- preventDefault() vs preventdefault()   you need the capitol D
- const task_el  not  const_task_el   a space instead of an underscore

Comment: yeah i was working on it earlier and realised  the submit had an uppercase S. Changed it and it works as expected. Cheers lad.

Answer (score 0):

In general minor errors here and there (like commented). Use the name attribute on the form and the input elements.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const form = document.forms.newtaskform;
  const list_el = document.getElementById('tasks');

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault(); //stops page refreshing when form submitted
    let form = e.target;
    
    const task = form.newtaskinput.value;

    let task_el = document.createElement("div");
    task_el.classList.add("task");

    let content_el = document.createElement("div");
    content_el.classList.add("content");
    content_el.innerText = task;

    task_el.appendChild(content_el);
    list_el.appendChild(task_el);
    form.reset();
  });
});
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>TO DO LIST</h1>
  <form name="newtaskform">
    <input type="text" name="newtaskinput" placeholder="What would you like to do today?" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Add task" />
  </form>

</header>
<main>
  <section class="taskslist">
    <h2>Tasks</h2>
    <div id="tasks"></div>
  </section>
</main>
```